# prop is undefined inside componentWillReceiveProps() method

Tags: react-native

I'm using ReactNative with Redux, and I have a reducer which returns an array of values.
I have the following component which should receive that array given by reducer.

I can successfully print the whole array inside `mapStateToProps` and inside `render()` method I can see a part of this array.
The problem is that inside `componentWillReceiveProps()` the array is undefined.

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
      }

      componentWillReceiveProps(){
        console.log("hey");  // I can see this in the terminal
        const { calculatedPercentages } = this.props;
        // here's the problem I get undefined 10 times
        for (let i=1; i<11; i++){
          console.log("test: "+calculatedPercentages[i]);
        }
        this.setState({myPercentages:calculatedPercentages})  
      }

      render() {    
        return (
          <View> 
          <Text>{this.props.calculatedPercentages[3]}</Text>  // this works and it prints out the correct value
          </View>
        );
      }


    const mapStateToProps = ({ myRed }) => {
      const { calculatedPercentages } = myRed;  
      // this loop works correctly, it shows me the 10 values I've inside the array
      for (let i=1; i<11; i++){
          console.log(calculatedPercentages[i]);
      }
      return { calculatedPercentages };
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`componentWillReceiveProps`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) method is passed the next set of props as the first parameter, you need to utilise it like so:

```
componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
  const { calculatedPercentages } = nextProps;

  for (let i=1; i<11; i++){
    console.log("test: "+calculatedPercentages[i]);
  }

  this.setState({myPercentages:calculatedPercentages})  
}
```

In your original code you're using the existing props, hence you don't see the update.